# What is the maximum length of a “chain” of symbolic links?

Tags: linux

What is the maximum length of a “chain” of symbolic links? (In
other words, if you start with a symbolic link to a file, how often can you
create a symbolic link that points to the previous symbolic link?)

Comment: 40 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53107

Comment: thanks! helped very much